# Why i do not gain performance using ClassMapAutoloader in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, autoloader

In my company we developing a ZF2 application, no programm;-), right now. We are at a point where we want to test some part of the application by bringing it into the public www.

We prepared a STAGE-environment and i do some performance tuning now. I read that using the `ClassMapAutoloader` is much faster than the `StandardAutoLoader` like described e.g. http://samminds.com/2012/11/zf2-performance-quicktipp-2-classmap-autoloading/ . I do understand why it should be faster but in my case i profiled the site with and without `ClassMapAutoloader` using `xdebug` profiling, WinCacheGring/QCacheGrind and it is **slower** about 0,2%.

Does anyone has an idea why this could be slower?

I am using CentOS and PHP Version => 5.6.12

*EDIT ADDED INFORMATION:*

Example of one autoload_classmap.php:

```
    <?php
// Generated by ZF2's ./bin/classmap_generator.php
return array(
    'Search\Elasticsearch\Document\AbstractDocument'          => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Elasticsearch/Document/AbstractDocument.php',
    'Search\Elasticsearch\Document\ArticleDocument'           => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Elasticsearch/Document/ArticleDocument.php',
    'Search\Elasticsearch\Document\BookingDocument'           => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Elasticsearch/Document/BookingDocument.php',
    'Search\Elasticsearch\Document\DocumentType'              => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Elasticsearch/Document/DocumentType.php',
    'Search\Elasticsearch\Document\InvoiceDocument'           => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Elasticsearch/Document/InvoiceDocument.php',
    'Search\Elasticsearch\Document\OfficeDocument'            => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Elasticsearch/Document/OfficeDocument.php',
    'Search\Elasticsearch\Document\OfficeMemberDocument'      => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Elasticsearch/Document/OfficeMemberDocument.php',
    'Search\Elasticsearch\Document\ProductDocument'           => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Elasticsearch/Document/ProductDocument.php',
    'Search\Elasticsearch\Document\ProfileDocument'           => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Elasticsearch/Document/ProfileDocument.php',
    'Search\Elasticsearch\Document\RatingDocument'            => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Elasticsearch/Document/RatingDocument.php',
    'Search\Elasticsearch\Document\AbstractWebSearchDocument' => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Elasticsearch/Document/AbstractWebSearchDocument.php',
    'Search\Elasticsearch\AutoSuggestionQueryHandler'         => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Elasticsearch/AutoSuggestionQueryHandler.php',
    'Search\Elasticsearch\SearchStatisticIndexHandler'        => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Elasticsearch/SearchStatisticIndexHandler.php',
    'Search\Elasticsearch\TermRecognizerQueryHandler'         => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Elasticsearch/TermRecognizerQueryHandler.php',
    'Search\Elasticsearch\SearchIndexHandler'                 => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Elasticsearch/SearchIndexHandler.php',
    'Search\Elasticsearch\SearchQueryHandler'                 => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Elasticsearch/SearchQueryHandler.php',
    'Search\Elasticsearch\TermRecognizerIndexHandler'         => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Elasticsearch/TermRecognizerIndexHandler.php',
    'Search\Exception\Exception'                              => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Exception/Exception.php',
    'Search\Factory\AutoSuggestQueryHandlerFactory'           => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Factory/AutoSuggestQueryHandlerFactory.php',
    'Search\Factory\AutoSuggestServiceFactory'                => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Factory/AutoSuggestServiceFactory.php',
    'Search\Factory\DocumentStorerServiceFactory'             => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Factory/DocumentStorerServiceFactory.php',
    'Search\Factory\QueueWorkerServiceFactory'                => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Factory/QueueWorkerServiceFactory.php',
    'Search\Factory\SearchIndexHandlerFactory'                => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Factory/SearchIndexHandlerFactory.php',
    'Search\Factory\SearchQueryHandlerFactory'                => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Factory/SearchQueryHandlerFactory.php',
    'Search\Factory\SearchServiceFactory'                     => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Factory/SearchServiceFactory.php',
    'Search\Factory\SearchSimpleServiceFactory'               => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Factory/SearchSimpleServiceFactory.php',
    'Search\Factory\SearchStatistikIndexHandlerFactory'       => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Factory/SearchStatistikIndexHandlerFactory.php',
    'Search\Factory\TermRecognizerServiceFactory'             => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Factory/TermRecognizerServiceFactory.php',
    'Search\Factory\TermrecognizerIndexHandlerFactory'        => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Factory/TermrecognizerIndexHandlerFactory.php',
    'Search\Factory\TermrecognizerQueryHandlerFactory'        => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Factory/TermrecognizerQueryHandlerFactory.php',
    'Search\Factory\RequestHandlerFactory'                    => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Factory/RequestHandlerFactory.php',
    'Search\Logger\LoggerInterface'                           => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Logger/LoggerInterface.php',
    'Search\Logger\StatisticLogger'                           => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Logger/StatisticLogger.php',
    'DatabaseQueue'                                           => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Queue/DatabaseQueue.php',
    'Search\Search\QueryWordReducer'                          => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Search/QueryWordReducer.php',
    'Search\Search\RecognizedTermConsumer'                    => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Search/RecognizedTermConsumer.php',
    'Search\Search\SearchService'                             => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Search/SearchService.php',
    'Search\Search\SuggestionListBuilder'                     => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Search/SuggestionListBuilder.php',
    'Search\Search\Util'                                      => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Search/Util.php',
    'Search\Search\ViewState'                                 => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Search/ViewState.php',
    'Search\Search\ViewStateToSearchRequestTransformer'       => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Search/ViewStateToSearchRequestTransformer.php',
    'Search\Search\SearchSimpleService'                       => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Search/SearchSimpleService.php',
    'Search\AutoSuggester'                                    => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/AutoSuggester.php',
    'Search\QueryCleaner'                                     => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/QueryCleaner.php',
    'Search\Request'                                          => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Request.php',
    'Search\RequestHandler'                                   => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/RequestHandler.php',
    'Search\SearchSource'                                     => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/SearchSource.php',
    'Search\Util'                                             => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/Util.php',
    'Search\QueueWorker'                                      => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/QueueWorker.php',
    'Search\AbstractDocumentStorer'                           => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/AbstractDocumentStorer.php',
    'Search\DocumentStorer'                                   => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/DocumentStorer.php',
    'Search\TermRecognizer'                                   => __DIR__ . '/src/Search/TermRecognizer.php',
    'Search\Module'                                           => __DIR__ . '/Module.php',
);
```

Extract from the correlating Module.php:

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig() {
    return [
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => [
            __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php'
        ],
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => [
            'namespaces' => [
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . str_replace('\\', '/', __NAMESPACE__)
            ]
        ]
    ];
}
```

I checked already that the Autoloader uses the classmap.

*EDIT ADDED INFORMATION:*
[image: Zend developer Toolbar 1]

[image: Zend developer Toolbar 2]

[image: Zend developer Toolbar 3]

Comment: Slower by how much? Also, xdebug profiling is for *debugging* performance issues, don't use it to measure performance, since it adds significant overhead and may skew your results.

Comment: Xdubug and webgrind makes a website much slower and should be used only in development. Show us your classmap_autoload.php and the config

Comment: @stanimir: For sure i use xdbug only in development ;-) sry for that misunderstanding

Comment: @tim: i did use xdebug because i did see that i do not gain any performance => so i decided to profile with xdebug to check if there is a difference before and after the change, i mostly use this procedure to check if changes results in better performance

Comment: @Gizzmo How big is Module.php?

Comment: @Stanimir: Most oft them, i have about 20 module.php in my project, are about 30 lines. Only 1 has baout 120 lines of code.

Comment: Install https://github.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools with https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyProfiler or https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule and show me a picture of the profiling data, so I can write an answer. classmap_autoload.php is just a small part of making ZF fast.

Comment: I added some screenshoots; because i nearly do not use any DB-Queries (only 1 for now) in the public area i did not install "github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyProfiler" but i installed "github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule", hope this helps.

Comment: Add Zend library to your `autoload_classmap.php`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer. Right now your app loads for half a second - 0.6s to be precise. So I the autoloader is doing his works. Your queries are also executed fast. There are two more ways I can think of to speed up your applications.

- First way - using template map

Locate your templatemap_generator.php file. It should be in your `vendor/zendframework/zendframework/bin` folder. Navigate to your module folder e.g. `Application` directory where the `src, view, config` folders are. Open a terminal and type php `../../vendor/zendframework/zendframework/bin/templatemap_generator.php` ZF will create a template map in your module directory. Now to use this template, simply modify your module.config.php file. The file structure is similar to the one from clasmap_autoloader.php

```
return array(
// Telling where the views are
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => include __DIR__ . '/../template_map.php', // <-- add this line. You can remove `template_path_stack`
),
```

In your controllersfor each action add a view template.
    public indexAction()
    {
        $view = new ViewModel();
        $view->setTemplate("aplication/index/index");
        return $view;
    }

- Second way - Using module cache in production environment.

Let's say you have this line in your `.htaccess - SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"`

In your `public/index.php` file if you haven't done something similar, add this:

```
/**
 * Set global ENV. Used for debugging
 */
if (isset($_SERVER['APPLICATION_ENV']) && $_SERVER["APPLICATION_ENV"] === 'development') {
    define("APP_ENV", 'development');
} else {
    define("APP_ENV", "production");
}
```

This will ensure that you have a global env across your application which says if debugging is on or off and it helps you avoid DRY code.
Now from your root folder open `config/application.config.php`

```
<?php

$modules = [];

if (APP_ENV === 'development') {
    $modules[] = 'ZendDeveloperTools';
    $modules[] = 'BjyProfiler';
    $modules[] = 'SanSessionToolbar';
}

$modules[] = 'Application';
$modules[] = 'Admin';

return [
    // This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
    'modules' => $modules,

    // These are various options for the listeners attached to the ModuleManager
    'module_listener_options' => [
        // This should be an array of paths in which modules reside.
        // If a string key is provided, the listener will consider that a module
        // namespace, the value of that key the specific path to that module's
        // Module class.
        'module_paths' => [
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ],

        // An array of paths from which to glob configuration files after
        // modules are loaded. These effectively override configuration
        // provided by modules themselves. Paths may use GLOB_BRACE notation.
        'config_glob_paths' => [
            'config/autoload/{{,*.}global,{,*.}local}.php',
        ],

        // Whether or not to enable a configuration cache.
        // If enabled, the merged configuration will be cached and used in
        // subsequent requests.
        'config_cache_enabled' => (APP_ENV === 'production'),

        // The key used to create the configuration cache file name.
        'config_cache_key' => md5('app_config'),

        // Whether or not to enable a module class map cache.
        // If enabled, creates a module class map cache which will be used
        // by in future requests, to reduce the autoloading process.
        'module_map_cache_enabled' => (APP_ENV === 'production'),

        // The key used to create the class map cache file name.
        'module_map_cache_key' => md5('module_map'),
        // The path in which to cache merged configuration.
        'cache_dir' => dirname(__DIR__)."/data/cache",

        // Whether or not to enable modules dependency checking.
        // Enabled by default, prevents usage of modules that depend on other modules
        // that weren't loaded.
        'check_dependencies' => (APP_ENV !== 'production'),
    ],

    // Used to create an own service manager. May contain one or more child arrays.
    //'service_listener_options' => [
    //     [
    //         'service_manager' => $stringServiceManagerName,
    //         'config_key'      => $stringConfigKey,
    //         'interface'       => $stringOptionalInterface,
    //         'method'          => $stringRequiredMethodName,
    //     ],
    // )

   // Initial configuration with which to seed the ServiceManager.
   // Should be compatible with Zend\ServiceManager\Config.
   // 'service_manager' => [],
];
```

`config_cache_*` will activate and cache your route config when your app is in production. All your module routes will be cached. Also If the website is in production the debugging modules will not be loaded.
You can replace `md5('app_config')` with whatever you want.

Comment: No problem for the late answer! Thx for the answer anyway. TemplateMap did not increase performance in any way, but the second, caching config, did improve performance. so thank you for that.

Comment: Would be nice if you accept my answer. :) Also, from the pictures above, I see that your I/O uses ~30mb of memory, so you have to dig inside your php code and improve it. Also if you use php 5.5+ i suggest you to upgrade to zend 2.5.1.

Comment: So your answer helped me but why the autoloading by classmap did not improve the performance is still unknown. I will wait for some time to see if someone can give me another tip about the autoloading. Afterwards i mark your anser as accepted cuz y really tried to help me:-)